# Is that possible to save data with form submission

Tags: php, form-submit, cakephp-4.x

controller code:

```
    public function login()
    {
        $this->LoadModel('Users');

        pr($this->data);
    }
```

View code:

```
<?php echo
$this->Form->create('Post').
$this->Form->control('email').'<br>'.
$this->form->label('password').'<br>'.
$this->Form->password('password').'<br>'.
$this->Form->submit('log in').
$this->Form->end();
?>
```

I fail to understand that Data is submitted to controller but to read data from controller. 
I get that data saved with controller but to access data variable ie submit form data unable to read to controller.

Comment: Do you want to post data in controller ? is it your question ?

Comment: yes thats my question.

Comment: i want to post data to controller.

Comment: yes i want to post data in controller so i can save data to database using insert command. please reply with an answer ASAP because i really want that code to work. purpose is to solve the question with answer that will allow me to save data to database after form submission to controller. be kind and reply ASAP. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get post data, use debug

```
debug($this->request->getData());
```

It's looking like you need all CRUD code.

So, you can create your user add.ctp file below

location : templates\Users\add.ctp

```
<?= $this->Form->create($user) ?>

<?php
   echo $this->Form->control('username');
   echo $this->Form->control('email');
   echo $this->Form->control('password');
?>

<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Then users controller look like

```
 UsersController/add method look like 

 public function add()
    {
        $user = $this->Users->newEmptyEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
    }
```

Do you need more ? 
Just need to give a simple command in your app folder to generate your CRUD.

give command

```
bin/cake bake all users
```

Assumption, users is your database table name. 
Then you will get add,edit,delete,view. 
[can see this tutorial for see how to give cake bake command](https://www.youtube.com)

Comment: thanks for your answer it solved most of it but save data to database would i get a response for that as well. pls thanks.

Comment: You will save data in database using method save(), 
you don't need write insert query. Insert query manage by save.

Comment: ok i get that so i let code flow but i was not able to save data because went to :
$this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));

Comment: This is unable to save then you got error. Here may have lots of problem. see in logs/error.log for details.

Comment: there is no error as such but only flash message but i'll read code still and get back. thanks.

Comment: Is it saving data ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206350/discussion-between-alimon-karim-and-prabhakar-siddhant).

Comment: Hi, i need a solution with CakePHP do not feel like posting a question about it because i can get a response so give a code to make two table association come together as one variable what code do i write for clean and simple implementation of code to get table data from two table i'll post a question to elaborate but it would put a my concern forward.